# What does dwFlagsAndAttributes = 0 mean in the CreateFile Method?

Tags: c#, winapi

So I'm using the [CreateFile function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a C# project that I'm currently working on. I've seen some examples that pass `0` as the argument for `dwFlagsAndAttributes`.

While I'm reading through the documentation it doesn't specify what setting `dwFlagsAndAttributes = 0` entails. Is this just a way of setting no flags or attributes?

The C# syntax for this method is:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, 
       FileAccess dwDesiredAccess, uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
       FileMode dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, 
       IntPtr hTemplateFile);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this just a way of setting no flags or attributes?

Exactly. Passing `0` for a parameter that is a set of bit flags (as is this parameter) means that none of the flags are set.

Answer (score 3):

Yup, it just means that the file is nothing special (ie, it doesnt match any of the [File Attribute Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Despite the name of `CreateFile` this function is used to both create and open files.  In the case where it is being used to open a file the `dwFlagsAndAttributes` argument is generally ignored.  It is likely that the cases you have seen are related to file opening vs. file creating.

If you are using this method with the intent of creating files I would use `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` (`0x80`).

Comment: Is there a difference between passing 0 and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL (in either opening or creating a file)?