# What does the dwDesiredAccess parameter set to 1 in the CreateFileA function mean?

Tags: windows

I can only find 0, generic_read and generic_write as options, but in the assembly code that I'm analyzing there is 1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does dwFlagsAndAttributes = 0 mean in the CreateFile Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997608/what-does-dwflagsandattributes-0-mean-in-the-createfile-method)

Comment: [`FILE_READ_DATA == FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY == 1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-access-rights-constants)

Comment: Note that `CreateFile` implicitly requests `SYNCHRONIZE` (i.e. the right to wait on the file object) and `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` (e.g. size, timestamps, and file attribute flags). If the caller has the right to list the parent directory, then the `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` right is granted implicitly. OTOH, without explicit `SYNCHRONIZE` access, a file isn't accessible in the Windows API. It can only be accessed with the native NT API (e.g. `NtOpenFile`).