# C++ Serial port with USB hub

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port, com-port

I want to connect a seairl port with C++ using USB hub (USB splliter). 
I have a code that works perfectly fine with my COM ports, but when I'm trying to use the USB hub, I get an error says the COM port not available (even though I see it in the device manager).

I there a way to connect a USB hub COM port in C++? 
I attached my current code if necessary. Thank you!

SerialPort.hpp:

```
/*
* Author: Manash Kumar Mandal
* Modified Library introduced in Arduino Playground which does not work
* This works perfectly
* LICENSE: MIT
*/

#pragma once

#define ARDUINO_WAIT_TIME 2000
#define MAX_DATA_LENGTH 1024

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class SerialPort {
private:
    std::string readBuffer;
    HANDLE handler;
    bool connected;
    COMSTAT status;
    DWORD errors;
public:
    explicit SerialPort(const char* portName, DWORD baudRate = CBR_9600);
    ~SerialPort();
    int readSerialPort(const char* buffer, unsigned int buf_size);
    int readSerialPortUntil(std::string* payload, std::string until);
    bool writeSerialPort(const char* buffer, unsigned int buf_size);
    bool writeSerialPort(std::string payload);
    bool isConnected();
    void closeSerial();
};
```

SerialPort.cpp:

```
/*
* Author: Manash Kumar Mandal
* Modified Library introduced in Arduino Playground which does not work
* This works perfectly
* LICENSE: MIT
*/

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "SerialPort.hpp"

SerialPort::SerialPort(const char* portName, DWORD baudRate) {
    this->connected = false;
    this->handler = CreateFileA(static_cast<LPCSTR>(portName),
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);
    if (this->handler == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
            std::cerr << "ERROR: Handle was not attached.Reason : " << portName << " not available\n";
        } else {
            std::cerr << "ERROR!!!\n";
        }
    } else {
        DCB dcbSerialParameters = { 0 };
        if (!GetCommState(this->handler, &dcbSerialParameters)) {
            std::cerr << "ERROR: Failed to get current serial parameters\n";
        } else {
            dcbSerialParameters.BaudRate = baudRate;
            dcbSerialParameters.ByteSize = 8;
            dcbSerialParameters.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
            dcbSerialParameters.Parity = NOPARITY;
            dcbSerialParameters.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;
            if (!SetCommState(handler, &dcbSerialParameters)) {
                std::cout << "ALERT: could not set serial port parameters\n";
            } else {
                this->connected = true;
                PurgeComm(this->handler, PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXCLEAR);
                Sleep(ARDUINO_WAIT_TIME);
            }
        }
    }
}

SerialPort::~SerialPort() {
    if (this->connected) {
        this->connected = false;
        CloseHandle(this->handler);
    }
}

// Reading bytes from serial port to buffer;
// returns read bytes count, or if error occurs, returns 0

int SerialPort::readSerialPort(const char* buffer, unsigned int buf_size) {
    DWORD bytesRead{};
    unsigned int toRead = 0;
    ClearCommError(this->handler, &this->errors, &this->status);
    if (this->status.cbInQue > 0) {
        if (this->status.cbInQue > buf_size) {
            toRead = buf_size;
        } else {
            toRead = this->status.cbInQue;
        }
    }
    memset((void*)buffer, 0, buf_size);
    if (ReadFile(this->handler, (void*)buffer, toRead, &bytesRead, NULL)) {
        return bytesRead;
    }
    return 0;
}

int SerialPort::readSerialPortUntil(std::string* payload, std::string until) {
    int untilLen = until.length(), len;
    do {
        char buffer[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
        int bytesRead = this->readSerialPort(buffer, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);
        if (bytesRead == 0) {
            int endIndex = this->readBuffer.find(until);
            if (endIndex != -1) {
                int index = endIndex + untilLen;
                *payload = this->readBuffer.substr(0, index);
                this->readBuffer = this->readBuffer.substr(index);
            }
            return bytesRead;
        }
        this->readBuffer += std::string(buffer);
        len = this->readBuffer.length();
    } while (this->readBuffer.find(until) == std::string::npos);
    int index = this->readBuffer.find(until) + untilLen;
    *payload = this->readBuffer.substr(0, index);
    this->readBuffer = this->readBuffer.substr(index);
    return index;
}

// Sending provided buffer to serial port;
// returns true if succeed, false if not
bool SerialPort::writeSerialPort(const char* buffer, unsigned int buf_size) {
    DWORD bytesSend;
    if (!WriteFile(this->handler, (void*)buffer, buf_size, &bytesSend, 0)) {
        ClearCommError(this->handler, &this->errors, &this->status);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool SerialPort::writeSerialPort(std::string payload) {
    return this->writeSerialPort(payload.c_str(), payload.length());
}

// Checking if serial port is connected
bool SerialPort::isConnected() {
    if (!ClearCommError(this->handler, &this->errors, &this->status)) {
        this->connected = false;
    }
    return this->connected;
}

void SerialPort::closeSerial() {
    CloseHandle(this->handler);
}
```

Comment: You're getting the error at the `CreateFileA` call, correct?  Make yourself a much smaller program that does only *that* for testing purposes, and double-check that you are passing the correct string for `portName`.  Use Device Manager to double-check whether your COM port number changes when you plug into a different hub (the root hub is also a hub).

Comment: @BenVoigt I did that. I know the port name, but from some reason I can connect it. If it's connect directly to my PC it's works fine. And yes, I get the "ERROR: Handle was not attached.Reason" etc. errror.
When I plug it directly to my PC, I use the name "\.\COM5" for example, it that the same name when I use that hub? (I'm talking about the "\.\COM" part, the number changes).

Comment: The `\\.\COM` prefix never changes, but the number can change if you move the USB serial adapter to a different computer or a different USB port on your computer (including from a port on the computer directly to a port on a hub).  If the number does change, Device Manager will show it.  Almost certainly everything will begin working right as soon as you use the correct `portName`.

Comment: OK, so if the prefix is constant, so I did the name correctly and it's still does not found it. It there anything more I can do?

Comment: Test using another program that uses COM ports.  I like PuTTY, there's also HTerm, Realterm, and so forth.  If they see the COM port and your program doesn't, your code is the problem.  If other programs don't see the COM port either, then the hardware is the problem.  Perhaps it isn't getting enough power when plugged in through a bus-powered hub.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Is there a way to "scan" all COM ports using code (not softwares)?

Comment: There is, but it isn't much fun.  Did you find a port name that works correctly in another program?  Does the same name work in yours?  (I will find a link to some of the existing questions here about "enumerating" COM ports using code)

Comment: http://www.naughter.com/enumser.html has 10 different approaches to finding serial port names in code.  I've always used the SetupDi* approach.